# Call a function only after other async/await functions are resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am calling 2 functions after a click event.

These function calls are present in a `singInHandler()`

```
  signInHandler = async () => {
      await window.customAuth.init(configFile);    
      await window.customAuth.login();
  }
```

**Requirement** : I want to call a 3rd function `window.customAuth.getId()` but it should be called only after the above 2 functions are executed with respective responses.

`window.customAuth.init(configFile)` @returns {Promise} A promise with the user data.

`window.customAuth.login()` @returns {Promise}

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens if you just call it after the 2 calls above?

Comment: What do you mean as "respective responses"? Successfully? Without any fails/errors?

Comment: [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) waits for the functions to resolve, so you can just place your third call after those two.

Comment: @EmileBergeron The 3rd function uses the successful responses of the above 2. Without them being executed first, the third one won't produce correct response.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Show what you've tried that doesn't work, explain what and why it doesn't work and the expected behaviour of what you'd like to accomplish _in the question description_.

Comment: @thewebtud does `window.customAuth.getId` require arguments? Did you mean to call it with the successful responses of the other two functions?

Answer (score 0):

Put your promises into the array and then call `Promise.race`, it will get resolved as soon as 1 promise gets resolved.

or shorter:

```
Promise.race([window.customAuth.init(configFile), window.customAuth.login()]).then(() => {
    // logic here
})
```

Comment: The condition of the OP was not that "one" of those promises should be solved, at least not that i understood it that way. Also racing makes not really sense here because both promises are fired at the same time and that's different than what OP wrote in the original code.

Answer (score -1):

You can just repeat what you already did.

```js
signInHandler = async () => {
      await window.customAuth.init(configFile);    
      await window.customAuth.login();
      await window.customAuth.getId();
  }
```

If you want to check return-values of the previous 2 functions, then... just do it.

```js
signInHandler = async () => {
      const result1 = await window.customAuth.init(configFile);    
      const result2 = await window.customAuth.login();
      if (result1 === true || check whatever you want) {
            await window.customAuth.getId();
      }
  }
```